# How to modify CSS float label on per input basis

Tags: css, css-animations

In my project I am using some CSS code to create a floating label for my form inputs. The original code for the floating label can be found [here](https://codepen.io/MichaelArestad/pen/ohLIa) for reference.

However since this code contains a number of floating label examples I have extracted the compiled CSS for the one I am interested in (balloon) and created an example below with my modifications. Specifically I have added a value to the input fields.

```css
.balloon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #377D6A;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: 0;
  text-indent: 60px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.balloon::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #efefef;
  text-indent: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.balloon + label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 8px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #032429;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(19, 74, 70, 0);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: rgba(122, 184, 147, 0);
}
.balloon + label:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid rgba(122, 184, 147, 0);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.balloon:focus,
.balloon:active {
  color: #377D6A;
  text-indent: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.balloon:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.balloon:active::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
}
.balloon:focus + label,
.balloon:active + label {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(19, 74, 70, 0.4);
  background: #7ab893;
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}
.balloon:focus + label:after,
.balloon:active + label:after {
  border-top: 4px solid #7ab893;
}


@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600,300,800);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  background: #efefef;
}

.row {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 30px;
  background: #032429;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}


.row:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: -5000px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15000px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: inherit;
}
.row:first-child {
  padding: 40px 30px;
}

.row span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span>
    <input class="balloon" id="state" type="text" value="AR" placeholder="Liquid, solid, gaseous..." /><label for="state">State</label>
  </span>
  <span>
    <input class="balloon" id="planet"  value="Earth" type="text" placeholder="Probably Earth" /><label for="planet">Planet</label>
  </span>
  <span>
    <input class="balloon" id="galaxy" type="text" value="This is a test" placeholder="Milky Way?" /><label for="galaxy">Guardians of the Galaxy</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

The question I have, if you look at the third input, is how to adjust spacing for the label so they dont overlap. I realize that I can change the text-indent in the balloon class but that will change the spacing for all the inputs.

Is there a way on an individual basis I can adjust the spacing to account for different lengths in labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an extra class to "Gardians" and style that to have a little more with.

Then (and I can't believe I'm about to say this) use `!important` on the active `text-indent` to overcome the extra specificity of the new class.

```css
.balloon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #377D6A;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: 0;
  text-indent: 60px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

/*Wide Version - can be applied to more elements*/
.balloon.wide {  
  text-indent: 200px;
}

.balloon::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #efefef;
  text-indent: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.balloon + label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 8px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #032429;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(19, 74, 70, 0);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: rgba(122, 184, 147, 0);
}
.balloon + label:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid rgba(122, 184, 147, 0);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.balloon:focus,
.balloon:active {
  color: #377D6A;
  /*Note !important*/
  text-indent: 0 !important;
  background: #fff;
}
.balloon:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.balloon:active::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
}
.balloon:focus + label,
.balloon:active + label {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(19, 74, 70, 0.4);
  background: #7ab893;
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}
.balloon:focus + label:after,
.balloon:active + label:after {
  border-top: 4px solid #7ab893;
}


@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600,300,800);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  background: #efefef;
}

.row {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 30px;
  background: #032429;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}


.row:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: -5000px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15000px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: inherit;
}
.row:first-child {
  padding: 40px 30px;
}

.row span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span>
    <input class="balloon" id="state" type="text" value="AR" placeholder="Liquid, solid, gaseous..." /><label for="state">State</label>
  </span>
  <span>
    <input class="balloon" id="planet"  value="Earth" type="text" placeholder="Probably Earth" /><label for="planet">Planet</label>
  </span>
  <span>
    <input class="balloon wide" id="galaxy" type="text" value="This is a test" placeholder="Milky Way?" /><label for="galaxy">Guardians of the Galaxy</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

[I normally avoid `!important` like the plague](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used) but in this case it makes sense. You could avoid it by using more specific selectors for your active state

```
.balloon:focus,
.balloon:active,
.balloon.wide:focus,
.balloon.wide:active, {
  color: #377D6A;
  text-indent: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works as coded. The thing is that I am using this css in Vuejs, and when I try to modify it to a specific input like this, the animation to move the input value to the left stops working.

Comment: Sorry went over edit time limit. I meant to say, the thing is that I am using this css in Vuejs, and when I try to modify it to a specific input like this, the animation to move the input value to the left stops working. Since I am not that knowledgeable about CSS, thought it was directly related to the CSS I was trying, but now I see it has something to do with the using it Vuejs. Any idea why this would happen? Just to clarify, both animations works if I use the CSS as is. If I modify it like the above then the label animation works but the ease-in-out of the value does not.

Comment: Sorry I had made a mistake in modifying the CSS as you described. It works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

target the input value

```css
input[value="This is a test"] {text-indent:170px; }
.balloon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #377D6A;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: 0;
  text-indent: 60px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.balloon::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #efefef;
  text-indent: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.balloon + label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 8px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #032429;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(19, 74, 70, 0);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: rgba(122, 184, 147, 0);
}
.balloon + label:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid rgba(122, 184, 147, 0);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.balloon:focus,
.balloon:active {
  color: #377D6A;
  text-indent: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.balloon:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.balloon:active::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
}
.balloon:focus + label,
.balloon:active + label {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(19, 74, 70, 0.4);
  background: #7ab893;
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}
.balloon:focus + label:after,
.balloon:active + label:after {
  border-top: 4px solid #7ab893;
}


@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600,300,800);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  background: #efefef;
}

.row {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 30px;
  background: #032429;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}


.row:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: -5000px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15000px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: inherit;
}
.row:first-child {
  padding: 40px 30px;
}

.row span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span>
    <input class="balloon" id="state" type="text" value="AR" placeholder="Liquid, solid, gaseous..." /><label for="state">State</label>
  </span>
  <span>
    <input class="balloon" id="planet"  value="Earth" type="text" placeholder="Probably Earth" /><label for="planet">Planet</label>
  </span>
  <span>
    <input class="balloon" id="galaxy" type="text" value="This is a test" placeholder="Milky Way?" /><label for="galaxy">Guardians of the Galaxy</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: this one input[value="This is a test"] {text-indent:170px; }

Comment: I tried this and it works in this one instance. However, I do have a lot of input fields who's value will change depending upon the previous saved data, so I don't think this would work in my case.